# Find $f(x)$ where $x\in[0,1], f(x) =\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{k}((1-x)^2x^n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Find $f(x)$ where
$$x\in[0,1]$$
$$f(x) =\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{k}((1-x)^2x^n)$$

I thought maybe expand the inner sum equation to $x^n-2x^{n+1}+x^{n+2}$ but I don't see how it helps me.

Comment: **Hint:** Consider limit for cases $x \in [0,\,1)$ and $x=1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $f_k\colon x\in [0,1]\mapsto \sum_{n=1}^k (1-x)^2 x^n$, first note that $f_k(1) = 0$ for all $k$; so that $f(1) = 0$ as well. It remains to deal with the other cases, i.e. $x\in[0,1)$.

You were on the right track -- expanding the square is a good idea: for $x\in[0,1)$,

$$
f_k(x) = \sum_{n=1}^k x^n - 2x\sum_{n=1}^k x^n + x^2\sum_{n=1}^k x^n.
$$
Using the fact that, for $\lvert x\rvert < 1$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$ converges* and is equal to $\frac{x}{1-x}$, can you conclude?

*If this is not a known result, try to prove it starting by the  fact that $\sum_{n=1}^k x^k = x\frac{1-x^k}{1-x}$ for $x\neq 1$ (this is a geometric sum).

Comment: You're welcome!